# [android][conscrypt][Amazon Fire TV] ssl == null NPE at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write

Tags: java, android, okhttp, google-conscrypt

Getting this exception in production app. But unable to reproduce this issue.

**Exception Stacktrace**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: ssl == null
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(NativeCrypto.java)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:824)
   at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(OutputStreamSink.java:56)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:103)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:247)
   at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.applyAndAckSettings(Http2Writer.java:79)
   at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.applyAndAckSettings(Http2Connection.java:759)
   at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable$settings$$inlined$execute$1.runOnce(Http2Connection.java:218)
   at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.runTask(TaskRunner.java:115)
   at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.access$runTask(TaskRunner.java:41)
   at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$runnable$1.run(TaskRunner.java:64)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

**Device Info**

- Android OS: Android 7.1.2
- Fire OS: Fire OS 6
- Model: Fire TV Stick 4K

Issue also reported in https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/1083